# When will document is validated against the schema.xml in SOLR

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj, solr4, solrcloud

I am submitting the indexing request through SolrJ but not doing hard commit. The commit is handle as part of solrconfig.xml but my  doubt is that, at what stage the document is validate against the schema.xml. Is it during the index submission or during the actual commit happens, because somewhere i read that actual schema.xml validation will happen only  when commit is issued to solr, is it true?
Can anyone clarify on that.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you take this question up on the solr users mailing list. There'll be a much greater chance of getting a proper answer there.